# Настройка стилей для каждого браузера.

Tags: css

Вообщем столкнулся с проблемой в стилях. Настраивал сайт для хрома, а сегодня заметил что в IE все сбивается, изображения гдето в стороне. Посоветовали сбросить стили в браузерах

```
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
```

Это не помогло, лишь чуть чуть поправило положение. Подскажите как можно настроить определенный стиль для каждого из браузеров. Не судите строго, впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего, перед тем, как верстать, сбросить все стандартные настройки браузеров (отступы, размеры шрифтов и т.п., которые браузер рендерит по дефолту) с помощью [reset.css](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/css/45296/)

А так, если во всех браузерах все хорошо, а в каком-то одном полная джигурда, то нужно использовать [css хаки](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=css%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8&clid=1823013&lr=213)

Answer (score 1):

для IE также есть условные комментарии.