# Форма отображается по разному в разных браузерах

Tags: css

Я только начинаю разбираться в CSS, так что возможно ответ на мой вопрос лежит на поверхности, но я уже битый час не могу разобраться. Есть форма обратной связи, в хроме отображается отлично, а в мозиле вот так http://prntscr.com/adir37, в сафари отступ еще больше.. Подскажите в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: потому что у браузеров разные дефолтные стили.

Comment: а как исправить это? Что б отображалось одинаково?

Comment: ответ намбер один отсюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82987/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Выложите сюда пример вашего кода, чтобы можно было сказать что конкретно исправить. А вообще, верстайте не под хромом, чтобы избежать неприятные сюрпризы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать вендорные префиксы.
Это приставки, используемые производителями браузеров для экспериментальных, еще не принятых в стандарт, CSS-свойств.

1. `-o-` — префикс для браузера Опера
2. `-moz-` — префикс для браузеров из семейства Mozilla
3. `-webkit-` — префикс для браузеров, построенных на движке Webkit, в частности Safari и Chrome
4. `-icab-` — префикс для браузера iCab
5. `-khtml-`. KHTML — компонент для просмотра HTML документов разработанный для среды KDE для UNIX-систем.

Для этого перед экспериментальным или нестандартным CSS-свойством написать соответствующий префикс, например, свойство text-overflow Opera не поймет, если не написать его таким образом: `-o-text-overflow` .